# Laravel 5 - How to create queue table with Command Prompt in Windows 8.1

Tags: php, email, laravel, queue

I am using Laravel 5 on my local with Windows 8.1. I successfully installed laravel with windows, it was hard because laravel's official documentation never talk about windows. However, I want to add a new table in my Database using Artisan Command. As you can already guess, it's not working on PC. I open command prompt as administrator and type this :

```
php artisan queue:table
```

This is probably working on a Mac or Linux but not on Windows...is there any artisan command to do the exact same thing but for PC?

I actually just need to create this table and I can't find anywhere the structure of this table. Thx!

Comment: Well what's the exact problem, what error are you getting when trying to run the command? The `artisan` commands work the same on all operating systems, they're not platform specific, they're scripts run via the PHP CLI.

Comment: My bad :) Thanks to pointing me out my problem : I had to go in laraval folder where artisan file was, then do my artisan command. I feel so dumb, lol. Could you please post an answer so I can accept it? :) Thx a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Step 1

You have to have PHP installed and be able to run in from the command prompt. Test that by typing:

```
php -v
```

If you get a version number and some other details proceed with Step 2, otherwise follow [this tutorial on sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-php-on-windows/) at least until point 4. The most important part being the adding of your PHP directory (where `php.exe` is located to the PATH system variable). After doing that, make sure to re-open CMD.

### Step 2

Artisan is actually just a normal PHP file with no extension. You have to be in your project directory to run it. Make sure that's the case.

```
> cd C:\Path\To\Laravel\Project
> php artisan queue:table
```

### Step 3

If you get some kind of error from `php artisan *` the next step mostly depends on that error. If it can't connect to the DB for example, you should first make sure that the credentials are configured correctly. If you have an error you don't understand, look it up online and if that doesn't help, post it along with your question.

Comment: Awesome! I was so wrong in the whole situation lol. I missed that step 2, I needed to be in my laravel folder where the artisan file was. Great and thank you for taking your time with this perfect explanation. I get it now :) +1 !